# extjs dataview XTemplate refer to previous record values

Tags: extjs4

I'm using an `XTemplate` to render rows in a `dataview`, and I can refer to the data in the current record by name:

```
xtype : 'dataview',
tpl : new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=\".\"><div>{cost}</div></tpl>')
```

this is fine, but I'd like to be able to refer to the previous record in the dataset, to do some switching based on whether the value is greater or less than in the previous record.

Is this possible, and if so, how?  From the doco it would seem to be possible using xindex somehow?

Thanks,

Comment: look at the 'Execute arbitrary inline code with special built-in template variables' of the XTemplate doco, there is a `parent` variable

Comment: I saw the `parent` var, but still unsure how to reference the sibling..?

Comment: I hope you can use `parent[xindex-1]` somehow. can you try to console.log() the parent object to see whats in it?

Comment: I was able to do `<tpl if=\"cost &gt; [parent[xindex].cost]\">` - thanks.  Do you want to formally answer this question so I can accept it, or shall I?

Comment: p.s. not (xindex-1) because xindex starts at 1 (for some reason)

Comment: you can cause I give only a hint, you solved it

Answer (score 1):

the sibling can be referenced as:

```
tpl : new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=\".\"><div>{[parent[xindex].cost]}</div></tpl>')
```

Note that we do not decrement xindex, because it starts at 1, not 0